# Impact of stopping Workflow Timer Service on SharePoint 2010 server

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow-activity, timer-service

I have a farm of 4 servers ( 2 WFE and 2 App ) and on both the App servers i would like to stop the workflow timer service.

What would be the impact of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule for SharePoint Workflow Timer service is:

- Start the Web Application Service on all servers that have the
  Workflow Timer Service running.

Or

- Disable the Workflow Timer Service on servers that are not running
  the Web Application service.

[Read more here](https://support.microsoft.com/zh-tw/help/2674684/sharepoint-2010-workflow-fails-to-run-after-pause)

If you stop the Workflow timer but Web applcation service is running then you will not run properly.

[Also read this](https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1004)